# Set visibility for a group of images

Tags: android, imageview, visibility

Let's say I have 4 images:

```
ImageView a = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.a);
ImageView b = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.b);
ImageView c = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.c);
ImageView d = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.d);
```

And then I set the visibility of those images by this:

```
a.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
b.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
c.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
d.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Is there anyway I can group those 4 images and then set the visibility to that group of images?

Something like this:

```
images[] = {a,b,c,d};
images.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use a `ViewGroup` your basic idea is good. I use it often. Just do

```
    ImageView images[] = {a,b,c,d};
    for (ImageView view : images) {
        view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
```

Comment: Just tested your code and it works perfectly! Thanks a lot for all the answers.

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach would be to have all the views in the same `ViewGroup` i.e. a layout and then set the visibility of the group in order to apply it to all children. But this really depends on how the views are laid out in the first place.

Comment: Thanks a lot and appreciate your answer... The solution was given by Floris!

Answer (score 0):

You can put all those images in layout and then control visibility of that layout.